# iBatis 3 not backward compatible?

Tags: upgrade, ibatis, backwards-compatibility, mybatis

1. Does anyone know why the API is not backward compatible?
2. Is it still thread safe?
3. Anyone know of any migration document from 2.x to 3.x?

Comment: note that you are expected to mark answers that work for use as accepted (tick below the vote counter)

Answer (score 2):

Answers for almost all your questions you may find in ["What's new in iBATIS 3"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ibatis3/) paper (from IBM):

> **Summary**: iBATIS is a project used primarily for data access object (DAO) and object-relational mapping (ORM). You can use it to easily work with Java™ objects and databases. The update for iBATIS 3 beta 9 was posted 23 Jan 2010. iBATIS 3 is a **completely rewritten** version of iBATIS and includes some **significant updates**. This article introduces some of what's new in iBATIS 3.

Another paper is ["Migrating from iBatis 2.x to 3.0"](http://fschiettecatte.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/migrating-from-ibatis-2-x-to-3-0/) written by François Schiettecatte.

The list of compatibility issues for iBatis/mybatis [between 2.3.4 and 3.0.4 versions](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/mybatis.html) you can find in the [Java Upstream Tracker](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully backward compatible. I mean it is not a drop in replacement, and everything will not work if you just replace the Jar file.

There are some namespace changes and API update you will have to take case yourself in your source, xml config and spring configuration file.

For example, myBatis 3 does not compatible with the build-in "ibatis" support ship from spring, as the API changes. But version 3 ship with it own spring beans that you can run perfectly with some changes.